# Workaround for CASSANDRA-12813: NPE in auth for bootstrapping node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a cassandra 3.9 production cluster and I am trying to add a node to that cluster. However I am seeing this issue.

CASSANDRA-12813 NPE in auth for bootstrapping node
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12813

Shy of upgrading my production cluster to 3.11 (which I may not be able to do immediately), is there a known workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

An undocumented (but **works**) way around this is to copy "system_auth" directory from another node and place it in the new node's data directory. Start Cassandra only after this step. This way setting up new auth table during bootstrap will be bypassed with the existing content. The content from the system_auth SSTables will not cause any harm, as its a copy of the users/roles belonging to tokens corresponding to that other node. Once copied repair, will take the responsibility of cleaning it up, if the tokens corresponding doesn't belong there.

Once the node has successfully been able to bootstrap, do a "nodetool repair" on system_auth keyspace and it would take care of the exact replica copies.